What Do We Use For the Android MusicKit Developer Token?
I am attempting to use Apple's MusicKit SDK for Android. Adding their authorization SDK went fine, and I can launch the Apple Music app to request authorization. However, I keep getting TOKEN_FETCH_ERROR in the response, suggesting that Apple does not like my developer token.
In my call to createIntentBuilder() on Apple's AuthenticationManager, where I am supposed to pass my developer token, what exactly is that token?
The .p8 file that I got from developer.apple.com is an encoded certificate, with four encoded lines between the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY-----. I am under the impression that we are to use this .p8 file as the developer token, but I have tried each of the following:

The verbatim contents of the .p8 file, including all newlines
The contents consolidated onto one encoded line between the BEGIN and END lines
Just the encoded contents, all on one line

None seem to work — they all give me TOKEN_FETCH_ERROR responses. The key itself is enabled for "Media Services (MusicKit, ShazamKit, Apple Music Feed)", which feels like the right option.
interface AppleMusicAuth {
    sealed interface AuthResult {
        data class Success(val musicUserToken: String) : AuthResult
        data object Failure : AuthResult
    }

    fun buildSignInIntent(): Intent
    fun decodeIntentResult(intent: Intent?): AuthResult
}

class AppleMusicAuthImpl(private val context: Context) : AppleMusicAuth {
    private val authManager = AuthenticationFactory.createAuthenticationManager(context)

    override fun buildSignInIntent() =
        authManager.createIntentBuilder(context.getString(R.string.developer_token))
            .setHideStartScreen(true)
            .setStartScreenMessage("hi!")
            .build()

    override fun decodeIntentResult(intent: Intent?): AppleMusicAuth.AuthResult {
        val rawResult = authManager.handleTokenResult(intent)

        return if (rawResult.isError) {
            Log.e("test", "Error from Apple Music: ${rawResult.error}")

            AppleMusicAuth.AuthResult.Failure
        } else {
            Log.d("test", "musicUserToken ${rawResult.musicUserToken}")

            AppleMusicAuth.AuthResult.Success(rawResult.musicUserToken)
        }
    }
}

In the above code, I am going through the rawResult.isError branch, and the log message shows that the error is TOKEN_FETCH_ERROR.

According to the documentation, it says that TOKEN_FETCH_ERROR is caused by: indicates error in fetching music token, say due to developer token invalid/exipred.. Have you used the TokenProvider to create a token?

@tomerpacific: TokenProvider is an interface. I do not see how to create a token that way. I have posted my code in an edit to the question. Thanks!

Upshot: the .p8 file is used to sign a JWT; it is not itself the developer token. See the accepted answer for details.

This answer tries to provide an end-to-end explanation of how to get a MusicKit developer token on Android. These instructions were accurate as of 2 August 2024. Things tied to Apple's Web site might have changed by the time that you read this. The code snippets were based on JJWT version 0.12.6.
Step #1: Set up an Apple developer account at https://developer.apple.com/
Step #2: Visit https://developer.apple.com/account, scroll down to the "Membership details" section, and note what value you have for "Team ID". This value appears to be semi-secret, so you may want to treat it akin to how you treat other secret values in your code base.
Step #3: On that same page, go to the "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" section and click on "Identifiers":

Step #4: Click the "+" sign next to "Identifiers":

Step #5: In the long list of identifier types, choose "Media IDs" and click the "Continue" button:

Step #6: In the "Register a Media ID" page, choose "MusicKit", fill in a suitable description, fill in a suitable identifier (following their instructions), and click "Continue". You can then click "Register" after confirming what you filled in to actually create the ID:

Step #7: After Step #6, you should have wound up back at the Identifiers page from Step #3, except that your identifier should appear there. If you wound up somewhere else, follow those first few steps to get back into the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" page.
Step #8: Click on "Keys" to visit the Keys page, then click the "+" button:

Step #9: On the "Register a New Key" page, check the "Media Services" option, then click the "Configure" button:

Step #10: On the "Configure Key" page, choose your identifier from Step #6 in the drop-down, then click Save:

Step #11: You should have wound up back on the "Register a New Key", with the "Configure" button now changed to an "Edit" button. Fill in a key name, then click "Continue". Then click "Register" after confirming what you filled in.
Step #12: You should wind up on a "Download Your Key" page. Click "Download" to download a .p8 file, and save it somewhere private and safe. Click "Done" when you are done.

Step #13: This should lead you back to the Keys page from Step #8, with your new key in the list. Click on it to view the key details. Note what value you have for "Key ID". This value appears to be semi-secret, so you may want to treat it akin to how you treat other secret values in your code base.
Step #14: Make a copy of the .p8 file, then edit that copy in a plain text editor (e.g., Sublime Text). Remove the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- lines and remove all newlines, so the seemingly-random text (actually some base64-encoded data) all appears on one line. Store this encoded private key akin to how you treat other secret values in your code. At this point, you have a total of three secrets: the team ID, the key ID, and the encoded private key (derived from the .p8 file).
Step #15: Add the JJWT library to your app.
Step #16: Create a function akin to the following:
    private fun buildDeveloperToken(p8: String, keyId: String, teamId: String): String {
        val priPKCS8 = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Decoders.BASE64.decode(p8))
        val appleKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(priPKCS8)
        val now = Instant.now()
        val expiration = now.plus(120, ChronoUnit.DAYS)

        val jwt = Jwts.builder().apply {
            header()
                .add("alg", "ES256")
                .add("kid", keyId)
            claim("iss", teamId)
            issuedAt(Date.from(now))
            expiration(Date.from(expiration))
        }.signWith(appleKey).compact()

        return jwt
    }

Here, p8 is the encoded private key derived from the .p8 file, keyId is the key ID, and teamId is the team ID. This code decodes p8 into a PrivateKey, builds a JWT token using the keyId and teamId, and signs it with the PrivateKey, following Apple's documentation. Note that this code sets the lifetime of the signature to be 120 days — the maximum is six months.
You can then use that buildDeveloperToken() function in things like createIntentBuilder():
fun buildSignInIntent() =
        AuthenticationFactory.createAuthenticationManager(context)
            .createIntentBuilder(buildDeveloperToken(...))
            .setHideStartScreen(false)
            .setStartScreenMessage("i can haz ur muzik?")
            .build()

(where ... is code that retrieves those three secrets from wherever you are storing them)

So this is the official way to create a developer token for the Apple Music SDK.
I'll copy it here and elaborate a bit:
Construct a developer token as a JSON object whose header contains:

The algorithm (alg) you use to sign the token, which should have a value of ES256

A 10-character key identifier (kid) key, obtained from your developer account


In the claims payload of the token, include:

The issuer (iss) registered claim key, whose value is your 10-character Team ID, obtained from your developer account (To locate your Team ID, sign in to your developer account, and click Membership in the sidebar. Your Team ID appears in the Membership Information section under the team name.)

The issued at (iat) registered claim key, whose value indicates the time at which the token was generated, in terms of the number of seconds since epoch, in UTC

The expiration time (exp) registered claim key, whose value must not be greater than 15777000 (6 months in seconds) from the current Unix time on the server


A decoded developer token has the following format:
{
     "alg": "ES256",
     "kid": "ABC123DEFG"
}
{
     "iss": "DEF123GHIJ",
     "iat": 1437179036,
     "exp": 1493298100
}

After you create the token, sign it with your MusicKit private key(.p8 file you have) using the ES256 algorithm.
Note
ES256 is the JSON Web Algorithms (JWA) name for the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) with the P-256 curve and the SHA-256 hash.
So, on Android using Kotlin and this library, it will look something like:
 fun generateToken() {
        val now = Date()
        val privateKeyBytes = byteArrayOf() // private key bytes
        val signingKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(privateKeyBytes)

        val jwt = Jwts.builder().apply {
            header().add("alg", "ES256").add("kid", "ABC123DEFG")
            claim("iss", "DEF123GHIJ")
            issuedAt(now)
            expiration(Date(now.time + 10 * 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60)) // exp = 10 days, can be up to 6 month

        }.signWith(signingKey).compact()

        println(jwt)
    }

This code is rather pseudo, meaning it may need adjustments/other library or its methods/something else to make it work - but I used this approach to create a proper JWT(not for Apple, though) and it worked.
Hope it helps.

That got me a lot closer, thanks! Keys.hmacShaKeyFor() returns a SecretKey, and we need a PrivateKey for signWith(). I had to use some other code to get a PrivateKey. See my answer for the details. I'll award the bounty in a bit -- SO is saying I can't do it for another 7 hours.

@CommonsWare yeah, I though the code would need some adjustments - since originally it was not for Apple Developer Token. Glad I could help. And thanks for the bounty!)
